# Trigger Event Javascript IE

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, internet-explorer-7

I got a simple problem and can't get it working:
I'm trying to trigger an event in IE 7. To do this, I tried following:

```
if (typeof fireEvent != 'function') {
    function fireEvent(target, evt) {
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            clickEvent.initMouseEvent(evt, true, true, window,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            return target.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        }
        else {
            return target.fireEvent("on" + evt);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. The event isn't triggered in IE 7.
Jquery trigger will work in IE 7, however, I can't use it, because it's creating a memory leak in my Java application (approx 400MB memory leak) and the script is dying because of this.

What I've tried is a simple login with Javascript like that (http://accounts.google.com/):

```
document.getElementById('Email').value = "%s";
document.getElementById('Passwd').value = "%s";
var signIn = document.getElementsByName('signIn')[0];
fireEvent(signIn, "click");
```

Both fields ("Email" and "Passwd") are getting filled, but the form isn't submitted.
As an alternative I tried using the "onsubmit" event. The last 2 lines can be changed to:

```
var gaiaLoginForm = document.getElementById("gaia_loginform");
fireEvent(gaiaLoginForm, "submit");
```

Once more: jQuery and any other big framework aren't useable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just "fire" an event like that in older IE. You have to tell the browser *what* you're trying to trigger, not only the type. The point is that you can change the property values of the object before firing it. Try this:

```
var evtObj = document.createEventObject();
target.fireEvent("on" + evt, evtObj);
```

Also, I'd suggest to investigate on the causes of your alleged memory leak.

(By the way, Javascript != Java.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried this already: changing the method fireEvent to: 
    function fireEvent(target, evt) {
....
        else {
            var evtObj = document.createEventObject();
            target.fireEvent("on" + evt, evtObj);
        }
isn't working. The event is somehow not triggered.

By the way: I Know Javascript != Java, I'm calling IE with Java and execute Javascript with Java in the IE, okay!? :P

Comment: Can you explain "isn't working"? I used that for years and always worked for me.

Comment: Ok: I'm testing this code using IE 9 Developer Tools (F12). I'm changing the browser mode to IE 7, page mode IE 7 and open the console. The script executes without any errors and warnings. Result: Both fields are filled, but the form isn't submitted - nothing is happening. Methods like submit() or click() aren't supported by the browser. You can test this yourself at http://accounts.google.com/ with the posted / and or edited script.

Comment: Okay, I debugged it now some further: Firing this event returns "undefined", because onclick / onsubmit isn't defined. However, I want to submit the form not trigger the onclick / onsubmit effect.

Comment: Why don't you just invoke the `submit` event of the form element? It's supported by IE7. The `onsumbit` property is supported only by form elements, but the `onclick` property is supported by almost every element since it bubbles up. Anyway, this is a live demo, I hope that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/QcaA4/

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I got it now. Additionally, window.onload and any other domready wrapper failed. Certain fields weren't available. I've changed it back now to document.forms[number].submit();. I'm getting no longer any error and the script executes properly. I had to wrap it in an intervall that checked every half a second if the page / dom element has been loaded finally.

Comment: I suggest to try to undestand why `window.onload` or something like `document.onreadystatechange` fail for you, since they're both well supported by IE7 and could save you from using a very ugly solution like timed checks for document readyness. What do you mean with "failed"? Some elements aren't present in the DOM when the event is triggered?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Some elements arem't present in the DOM when the event is triggered. Those elements are loaded with Ajax. However, there's no possibility to access / register a new event, that listens for the ajax result "event". The existing javascript is almost entirely obfuscated. Using a timeout won't work, as slow computers will need too long to load the content, using one of the existing events like window.onload or document.onreadsatechange will not work, as the dom isn't existing. What else is left then using setInterval and check for readyness?

Comment: If you have no control over the r `XMLHttpRequest` objects that the script creates, you're *almost* out of luck. There are the deprecated `MutationEvent`s that aren't even supported decently by IE9, or the draft `MutationObserver`s, supported by Chrome and Firefox IIRC, or the dirty trick to override the `XMLHttpRequest` object. I guess a timed check is fine here.